# ajax create %20 on space while submitting ....?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

php:

```
<div id="PROJECT_ENTRY" style="display:none">
                            <table align="center">
                                <tr><td>PROJECT ID:</td><td class="PROJECT_ID" ><input id="PROJECT_ID"  name="PROJECT_ID" class="PROJECT_ID" ></td></tr>
                                <tr><td>PROJECT NAME:</td><td class="PROJECT_NAME" ><input id="PROJECT_NAME"  name="PROJECT_NAME" class="PROJECT_NAME" ></td></tr>
                            </table>    
                        </div>
<td width="80px"><a href="javascript:projectform()"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>./images/addDetal.png" style='vertical-align:middle;' width='23' height='23' /></a></td>
```

---

```
 function projectform(){
                    $("#PROJECT_ENTRY").dialog({ 
                    modal: true,
                    width:400,
                    title:'NEW PROJECT ENTRY',
                    buttons: {
                         OK: function(){
                              var projectID=$("#PROJECT_ID").val();
                              var projectname=$("#PROJECT_NAME").val();

     var  baseUrl= "<?php echo base_url() . 'LOANENTRY/operate_project/'; ? "+projectID+'/'+projectname;
```

---

```
              $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",
                url: baseUrl,
                data: $('#PROJECT_ENTRY').serialize(),
                dataType: "html",
                success: function() {                     

                }
            });
              $(this).dialog( "close" );
                        },
                    CANCEL: function() {
                        $(this).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: And the question is ?

Comment: Lets assume it has something to do with the title, and yes, strings are encoded when sent to the server, but it shouldn't matter.

Comment: yes because `.serialize()` function convert string to standard URL-encoded notation. I think it will be better if you use `GET` method

Answer (score 0):

may be you need :

```
$.ajax({
   cache: false,
   type: "POST",
   url: baseUrl,
   data: "project_entry="+$('#PROJECT_ENTRY').val(),
   dataType: "html",
   success: function() {                     

   }
});
```

And receive with this PHP:

```
$p_entry = $_POST['project_entry'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the `%20` in php using [urldecode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

Comment: i think urlecode() decode() dont take = (), @, #
im using CI..  how to accept uri character done on stting config
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_()@\-'; but dint work